# Hokuyo Laser Scanner not updating fastly

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Hokuyo Laser the scan values are getting dealyed from gazebo

```
  <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
  <pose>0.0 0 0.0 0 -0 0</pose>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-1.58079</min_angle>
        <max_angle>1.58079</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.08</min>
      <max>5</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.01</stddev>
    </noise>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
    <always_on>1</always_on>
    <topicName>/sk/laser/scan</topicName>
    <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
  </plugin>
  <always_on>1</always_on>
  <update_rate>30</update_rate>
  <visualize>true</visualize>
</sensor>
```

[image: gazebo veiw]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348381/hokuyo-laser-scanner-not-updating-fastly/) by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-04-05**:
Could you formulate better your question? Show us more data about the problem. It helps us to help you.

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-06**:
Laser values are not getting accurately, laser is kind of blinking so some values are missing  from left and and right

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-04-06**:
I tried here your laser settings on my robot. And the laser is working fine.

https://pasteboard.co/J2zz95B.png

I just copy and paste what you post here. So the problem isn't in the code.

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-06**:
Then what could be the problem?
It's like the laser is flickering from left and right to some angle because of this laser values are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was checking here and increase the range tag

Try to increase `<min>0.08</min>`

The values are just an example, but it is a good start.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-06**:
Isn't the clip tag used in camera plugin?

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-04-06**:
Sorry, I'm out of my mind. Try to increase 0.08

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-06**:
No problem
Thanks I'll try it out

**Comment by [me_saw](https://answers.ros.org/users/52338/me_saw/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thank you:)   it solved the problem I increased the min to 0.28 and it's working perfectly. I guess the problem was the dimensions of my model

can you answer it separate so that I can mark it as correct.

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-04-06**:
I edited the comment. I'm glad to help ^^